# Passing Custom User Object to WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-membership

I've implemented a custom ASP.net membership provider to deal with forms authentication. The custom provider uses a custom User object for authentication and authorization. I was wondering If I can pass this object to each WCF call without adding it to the parameters list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using a MembershipProvider you can utalize that on wcf as well so both are secured by the same mechanism.

See this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) on msdn.

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   developers can take advantage of these
>   features for security purposes. When
>   integrated into an WCF application,
>   users must supply a user name/password
>   combination to the WCF client
>   application. To transfer the data to
>   the WCF service, use a binding that
>   supports user name/password
>   credentials, such as the WSHttpBinding
>   (in configuration, the wsHttpBinding
>   Element) and set the client credential
>   type to UserName. On the service, WCF
>   security authenticates the user based
>   on the user name and password, and
>   also assigns the role specified by the
>   ASP.NET role.

Another option would be to create a custom `IAuthorizationPolicy` that pulls off your user via

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<T>
```

And than setup your principal like the following:

```
evaluationContext.Properties[Constants.EvaluationContextPrincipal] = principal;
```

Here is some more information on creating a custom [IAuthroizationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751416.aspx).  With this method you could achieve what you want without passing your user to the method.

*Just be warned* if you go this route a crafty person could end up impersonating the user by simply suppling a bogus user in your header.

Using the asp.net membership provider for wcf would most likely get you what you are really after plus adding some security.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply. I've read the MSDN post and used my membership provider in the WCF application. I can access all Membership classes methods such as Membership.CreateUser(). However, I can retrieve the logged in USER. Do I need any specific syntax to do this?

Comment: @Nima M, It has been awhile since I used this, I *believe* after the user is authenticated by the wcf service you should be able to get the current user via `ServiceSecurityContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not add this to the parameters each method.

I do not know about your custom user object but as far as WS* and most security standards concerned, your user object will have username and password.

The answer depends on the binding you use. `BasicHttpBinding` or `BasicHttpContextBinding` can use HTTP authentication schemes while `WsHttpBinding` can use custom Message security which you can provide user name and password.

`BasicHttpContextBinding` is especially good since it can work with ASP NET session.